# HashSet: Cannot Remove An Object That Is Equal?

Tags: java, equals, hashset

In my code, I am trying to remove an element in a HashSet. I have overridden the equals method in my object.

```
for (BitVector bv : implicantsToDeleteViaBitVector) {
            System.out.println(bv + " , " + bv.hashCode());

            for(BitVector bvSetbv : bvSet){
                if(bv.equals(bvSetbv)){
                    System.out.println("match " + bv);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("No match " + bv + "," + bvSetbv);
                }
            }

            if(bvSet.remove(bv)){
                System.out.println("Remove");
            }else{
                System.out.println("No match found by remove");
            }
...
```

The problem is that my equals method will return true but my remove returns false on the same item being examined. This is the equals method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof BitVector))
        return false;
    BitVector v = (BitVector) o;
    boolean sameSize = mySize == v.getSize();
    boolean sameTerms = this.bitVectorList
            .containsAll(v.getBitVectorList());

    return (sameSize && sameTerms);
}
```

Does remove use the equals() method in a class? If so, then why is this code not working?

Answer (score 8):

You state:

> I have overridden the equals method in my object.

You need to also override the `hashCode()` method, and its contract should be that if two objects are equal, then their hashCodes also must be equal, although the converse is not necessarily true in that it is possible and allowed for two objects to have the hash code and not be equal, although this is something that should be avoided if possible.

Comment: I took a look at the hashCode and the hashCodes seem to be equal as well. Yet remove still comes back as false.

Comment: @Faytll: then you'll want to consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 7):

One of the possible problems is a mutable object (more accurately mutable hashcode). When you add an object to HashSet hashcode will be calculated only once. So if you change the object and try to 'remove' the SAME object from the collection the object will not be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

By overriding hasCode and equal method following way, you can fix your problem

```
  public int hashCode(){
        System.out.println("In hashcode");
        int hashcode = 0;
        hashcode = price*20;
        hashcode += item.hashCode();
        return hashcode;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        System.out.println("In equals");
        if (obj instanceof Price) {
            Price pp = (Price) obj;
            return (pp.item.equals(this.item) && pp.price == this.price);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


public String toString(){
        return "item: "+item+"  price: "+price;
    }
```